# AWS Gamelift Windows Access With SDK 5 or Above

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, rdp, fleet, amazon-gamelift

I'm trying to connect AWS Gamelift Windows 2016 instance from my local.
Procedure was simple `describe-instances`, `get-instance-access`, `update-fleet-port-settings`, rdp and go.
BUT :
Amazon made an update on Gamelift 5.0 or above sdk's no longer use `get-instance-access`. It says to use `get-compute-access` instead. This is written only in CLI and Amazon documents have nothing about this. 
BUT :
`get-compute-access` doesnt provide any kind of username or secret key to access instance. Instead it provides, temporary AccessKeyID, SecretAccessKey, SessionToken. I have checked their documentation here. What I see here is it gives credentials of gamelift s3. 
BUT :
When I tried to connect it via WinSCP, selected protocol as s3 placed accesskeyid, secretaccesskey, sessiontoken ( session token is in the advanced tab only), it gives me access denied. 
I couldnt find good documentary for it, could you please forward me some stuff to solve this ?